# How to require re-entering password confirmation for specific routes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, password-protection

I have a secret route in Laravel that should sit behind a password confirmation protection (Like GitHub sudo mode when you're about to delete a repo or add a collaborator)

```php
Route::get('/secret', 'DiariesController@index')->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

But already authenticated users can easily access the routes

What I want is an extra layer of protection against physical access to the user's device

Here's what I have tried so far

`DiariesController`

```php
public function index()
{
    if (session()->has('sudo')) {
        return view('secret.diaries');
    }
    auth()->logout();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

And in `LoginController`

```php
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    session(['sudo' => true]);
}
```

But this basically does nothing, I have to manually expire the `sudo` session key somehow

is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Laravel v6.2.0` release ships with a `new password confirmation feature`. This feature allows you to attach a password.confirm `middleware` to routes where you want a user to re-confirm their password. Considering your code your route will look like below.

```
Route::get('/secret', 'DiariesController@index')->middleware(['auth', 'verified','password.confirm']);
```

If you attempt to access the route, you will be prompted to confirm your password, similar to what you may have seen on other applications like GitHub.
For more info you can visit [this](https://blog.laravel.com/password-confirmation)

Thanks